# Error in gnome2 ip messenger start in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, ip, gnome2

After installation of gnome2 ip messenger in ubuntu 14.04
At the time of start I get following error.

Error information
file name:ipmsg.c
Function create_lock_file
line 157

Error Messege
tmp/g2ipmsg.lock errno : -11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)

Comment: I've just [solved](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632626/ip-messenger-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/633274#633274) it, using alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 GNOME then please look into the system tray after installing gnome2 ip messenger. Lock file error occur because you are attempting to open more than one instances of the application.Please refer the screenshot below on the right hand bottom corner.
[image]