# IP Messenger not working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, gnome, indicator

Do anybody got success using IP Messenger in ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?

I'm getting error while launching ip-messenger.

```
FileName:ipmsg.c
Function:create_lock_file
Line:157
Can not setup lock file:/tmp/g2ipmsg.lock errno : -11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Well, I can see g2ipmsg process using ps command:

```
ravi@dell:~$ ps -e | grep "ipmsg"
9266 ? 00:02:33 g2ipmsg
```

That means, after process is running its just not showing in notification area, and so If i try to re-launch Ip Messenger from dock, its showing error because `.lock` file is already created at `/tmp/g2ipmsg.lock` by previous process and its being used.

I've tried many solutions from other questions I've mentioned, but none of them worked for IP Messenger yet.

I know, there something to do with gnome notification panel for allowing ip-messenger icon to appear behind system clock. I did something for skype in past and its working now. May be I need to do same for ip-messenger too but don't remember what solution I used for skype.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After spending lot of efforts, I've found two solutions:

**1. Wine**

Install wine to run `IPMsg.exe` on ubuntu. But it has a problem while transferring files. Ubuntu system can only receive files form IPMsg if its running using wine. While sending files from Ubuntu to Windows based IPMsg it will show 0KB file size and it will not allow you to receive any files.

So if you are just looking for non-file transfer solution. Just install wine and run `IPMsg.exe`.

**2. [iptux (Preffered solution)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/iptux/)**

This is the solution I've used finally. Installed iptux in my ubuntu system and its all working now. I can send files to windows users who are using IPMsg.exe.

```
$ sudo apt-get install iptux
```

- Sending file from IPMsg (Windows system) to iptux(Ubuntu system)

[image: Sending file from IPMsg (Windows system) to iptux(Ubuntu system)]

- Receiving file at iptux (Ubuntu system)

[image: Receiving file at iptux (Ubuntu system)]

**Update:**
Sometimes iptux also unable to send file from Linux system to any other. In such case please try transferring directory instead files. It works.

Comment: After lots of trying I could not share file using iptux but your advice of transfereing dirs worked well. Thanks for advice.

Comment: @silverwolf Glad, it helped you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have another alternative: [PetaClone](http://www.vector.co.jp/download/file/unix/net/fh647212.html)

It uses Java so you may need to install Java Runtime Environment.

Comment: That's a pretty sketchy download page.

Comment: @KevinBowen in case you thinks link above is suspicious : http://ftp.vector.co.jp/64/72/1342/petaclone_h20150214_1.8.0.tgz