# IPmessenger not working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, gnome, lan

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have tried installing IP messenger on this and it showing error message like this,

```
FileName:ipmsg.c
Function:create_lock_file
Line:157
Can not setup lock file:/tmp/g2ipmsg.lock errno : -11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

I tried various methods to resolve this.

- /tmp is writable
- g2ipmsg.lock file exists
- issued permission 777 to g2ipmsg.lock
- At start there is two process running with name ipmsg in system monitor, so i removed all ipmsg processes and restarted the application again, no success
- Created file g2ipmsg.lock manually and set permission 777

none of this helped.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I know it is a little late, but try this 'https://askubuntu.com/questions/632626/ip-messenger-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts' link